# Javascript regular expression to capture every possible mathematical operation between parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to capture mathematical expressions between parenthesis in a string with javascript. I need to capture parenthesis that ONLY include numbers and mathematical operators [0-9], +, - , *, /, % and the decimal dot. The examples below demonstrate what I am after. I managed to get close to the desired result but the nested parenthesis always screw my regex up so I need help! I also need it to look globally, not for first occurence only.

let string = "If(2>1,if(a>100, **(-2*(3-5)*(8-2))***, **(1+2)**), **(3(1+2))** )";

What I want to do if possible is manage to transform this syntax

if(condition, iftrue, iffalse)

to this syntax

if(condition) { iftrue } else { iffalse }

so that it can be evaluated by javascript and previewed in the browser. I have done it so far but if the iftrue or iffalse blocks contain parenthesis, everything blows up! So I m trying to capture that parenthesis and calculate before transforming the syntax. Any advice is appreciated.

The closest i got was this /[\d()+-*/.]/g which gets whats i want but in this example

**(1+2)** **(1** < **1)** sdasdasd **(1*(2+3))**

instead of dismissing the (1<1) group entirelly it matches **(1** and **1)**. My ideal scenario would be

**(1+2)** (1<1) sdasdasd **(1*(2+3))**

Another example:
let codeToEval = "if(a>10, 2, 2*(b+4))";
codeToEval is the passed in a function that replaces a and b with the correct values so it ends up like this.
codeToEvalAfterReplacement = "if(5>10,2,2*(5+4))"; 
And now I want to transform this in

```
if(5>10) {
  2
} else {
  2*(5+4)
}
```

so it can be evaluated by javascript eval() and eventually previewed to the users.

Comment: can u add minimal working code ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current regex `/[\d()+-*/.]/g` will match single characters from the class
but multiple times because of the g flag, this is why (1 and 1) are still matched
in (1 < 1).

Based on your pattern requirements I would change it to `/\([-+*/%.0-9()]+\)/g`. 
This will match parentheses containing one or more of the characters you describe within them.

Note that your current pattern has a `-` somewhere in the middle of a class which can lead to weird behaviours because some regex engines will treat `+-*` within a class  as a range (plus through asterisk, which is a stange range). Notice I put `-` at the start of the class in the new pattern so it matches an actual `-`.

I've assumed there will be no empty parentheses (), if there are you can change `+` (one or more) after `]` to `*` (zero or more)
The g flag is still added so you match every one of such expressions.

I can't say with 100% certainty that the new regex will allow you to robustly transform the syntax you state, as it depends on the complexity of the 'iftrue' and 'iffalse' code blocks. See if you can make it work with the new pattern, otherwise you may want to look into other solutions for parsing code.

Comment: Well one weakness i found is in this example (5*(1+2) - 5*(1<2)). Instead of dismissing the entire formula it keeps selecting half of it resulting in an error cause there is a parenthesis not closed. If that could be fixed it would be great. Even without that being fixed it still is great so thank alot (!!!) because you cant possibly catch every stupid line of code the user will type! Will wait for a possible solution before giving you the accepted answer

Answer (score -1):

```
Call function in if parenthesis and all conditions in that function.    

if(test()){
    // if code 
    }else{
    // else code  
    }

    function test(){
      // check both cases here 
      if(case 1 && case 2){
        return true
      }
      return false; 
    }
```